# Configuring two DNS zones with named.conf

Tags: centos, dns-hosting

I am trying to configure DNS to run two domain names. I am able to do one domain but am not sure how to configure a second domain.

So for example:
test.com and test1.com on same machine.

How do i configure zone file and named.conf to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each domain would have its own zone file with its own records.  In `named.conf`, each zone gets its own declaration as such:

```
zone "example.com" in{
  type master;
  file "example.com.dns";
  // enable slaves only
  allow-transfer {192.168.23.1;192.168.23.2;);
};
```

So you would have one block for `example.com`, and another for `other-example.com` each directed to load the appropriate zone file from disk.

Answer (score 0):

sorry every one it was an eager question i got the answer.

```
named.conf = zone "test.com" IN {
        type master;
        file "data/test.com.zone";
        allow-update { none; };
               };
```

and simillar with zone files as stated in file "test.com.zone" inside data directory..